horizontal roullete fix bugging,displaying countdown and more
I was trying to make a horizontal roulette but there are a few things I do not understand. How do I make a countdown for roulette so countdown for example 15 s starts after every spin is done, and how do I display it?
How do I create the possibility to bet on number, color and to make roulette give parameter and how do I make roulette not buggy? It starts spinning and then just show some number, like animation is buggy.
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup multiple rows of colours, can also add and remove while spinning but overall this is easier.
    initWheel();
    
    // Start automatic spinning every 15 seconds
     setInterval(function() {
        var randomOutcome = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1; // Random number between 1 and 15
        spinWheel(randomOutcome);
    }, 15000);

    $('button').on('click', function() {
        var outcome = parseInt($('input').val());
        spinWheel(outcome);
    });
});

function initWheel() {
    var $wheel = $('.roulette-wrapper .wheel'),
        row = "";
    
    row += "<div class='row'>";
    row += "  <div class='card red'>1<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card black'>14<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card red'>2<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card black'>13<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card red'>3<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card black'>12<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card red'>4<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card green'>0<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card black'>11<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card red'>5<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card black'>10<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card red'>6<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card black'>9<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card red'>7<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card black'>8<\/div>";
    row += "<\/div>";
  
    for(var x = 0; x < 29; x++) {
        $wheel.append(row);
    }
}

function spinWheel(roll) {
    var $wheel = $('.roulette-wrapper .wheel'),
        order = [0, 11, 5, 10, 6, 9, 7, 8, 1, 14, 2, 13, 3, 12, 4],
        position = order.indexOf(roll);
            
    // Determine position where to land
    var rows = 12,
        card = 75 + 3 * 2,
        landingPosition = (rows * 15 * card) + (position * card);
    
    var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 75) - (75/2);
    
    landingPosition = landingPosition + randomize;
    
    var object = {
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) / 100,
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) / 100
    };
  
    $wheel.css({
        'transition': 'transform 10s cubic-bezier(0,' + object.x + ',' + object.y + ',1)', // Adjusted transition duration to 10s
        'transform': 'translate3d(-' + landingPosition + 'px, 0px, 0px)'
    });
  
    setTimeout(function(){
        $wheel.css({
            'transition': '', // Removed transition properties to reset
        });
        
        var resetTo = -(position * card + randomize);
        $wheel.css('transform', 'translate3d(' + resetTo + 'px, 0px, 0px)');
    }, 10 * 1000); // Adjusted reset timeout to match the transition duration
}


